# Scope/Group/Role/Permissions database architecture

Tags: database, database-design, orm, architecture

I'm building an internal web app and struggling with some DB design theory.

I've already got roles & permissions set up with Laravel & Entrust, but i'm trying to add extra functionality of Scopes and Groups and i'm not quite sure how to achieve it.

Given the following **scopes**:

- Company
- Team

and these **roles**:

- Admin
- Editor
- Author

and these **groups**(teams):

- Sales
- Development
- Design

I've already added scopes functionality which works great, so I can have a permission assigned to an admin in the company scope, but I want to be able to assign permissions to admins in a team scope according to the team they belong to.

The application will be quite expansive, but to keep it simple here i'll focus on a couple of use cases that I need to satisfy: Team and employee profiles.

**Team profiles**

- All employees can view all team profiles
- A company admin can edit all team profiles
- A team admin can edit their own team profile

**Employee profiles**

- All employees can view all employee profiles
- A company admin can edit all employee profiles
- A team admin can edit employee profiles within their own team
- An employee can edit their own profile

What's the best way to achieve this? Every time i try and approach it the solution feels overly complex and i bury myself in nested foreach loops. Is that just the bed i've made for myself or is there a better way to check for a permission against a role, scope & group at the same time?

Comment: You need to also add the permissions you wish to apply, presumably read, edit, delete and the objects (only profiles??) that you act on

Comment: Well yes, that much I understand, but consider a permission to edit the sales team. I can currently attach that to the admin role and the team scope, but then all team admins would be able to edit any team. I want to be able to compare optionally against the groups. How can I accomplish this cleanly in php?